# vga to usb adapter (or serial)

Tags: usb, vga

I'am developing a hobby operating system. Generally, I use qemu and serial console for video output as text like `-serial file:/tmp/qemu-video.log`. While debugging I don't need scrolling on monitor (I write everything to serial port and monitor). However while working on physical hardware, modern mainboards don't have serial port. So my method cannot work.

Hence, I try to find a solution for connection test computer's vga output to development computer's usb port with an adapter, then probably I can use `screen` command to gather output. I googled for **vga to usb**, however the results are about usb to vga.

Do anyone know such kind of adapter? Adapter can be a vga to serial (rs232).

Answer (score 0):

There are VGA capture devices, such as these [from StarTech](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00PC5HUA6) and [Gracetop](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08GYXZC3D), that *might* meet your need. Prices seem to range from ~US$60 and up.

Comment: these devices creates videos. I need to access as text mode (vga has two modes, text and graphics).

Comment: Sorry, @KazimSARIKAYA, I did not know about text mode... you've taught me something.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VGA_text_mode

Comment: Whilst they both refer to  protocols introduced in the graphics adapter in the IBM PS/2, VGA text mode and the VGA monitor interface have basically nothing to do with each other. Text mode is on the input, and the vga monitor interface the output. The graphics interface translates the text to video. As such these capture devices are capturing everything avaliable,  the text is not transmitted.